# match end of line not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi I have below code

```
www.dafont.com  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   5sce9gsn1ltj74brc02ls6gsg2
.dafont.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1409175984  msid    MC222
```

I need to get `5sce9gsn1ltj74brc02ls6gsg2` and `mc22`. I tried below code but its not working

```
 preg_match('/PHPSESSID (.*?)/',$getit,$session);
 preg_match('/msid  (.*?)/',$getit,$msid);
```

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: var_dump($session) is empty

Comment: Replace `.*?` with `.*`.

Comment: Using a non-greedy match at the end of a string doesn't make sense. It wants to return nothing.

Comment: @RohitJain : nope not working

Comment: @AnishaGowda that solution works for me; what does it do for you?

Comment: actually $getit is an file_get_contents of an text file , so may be its not working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments have gotten to the root of the problem: by using the question mark to indicate that your match is lazy (as opposed to the default of greedy), it's making a *minimal* match, which is, in this case...nothing.

Consider:

```
$input = "foo bar";
preg_match( '/foo (.*)/', $matches );    // matches 'bar'
preg_match( '/foo (.*?)/', $matches );   // matches ''
```

The only sensible use of the lazy quantifier is when something follows it.  So you could use this:

```
preg_match( '/foo (.*?)$/', $matches );  // matches 'bar'
```

But it's kind of unnecessary.

To understand the whole greedy/lazy difference, here's where it makes sense to use lazy matches instead.  Let's say you're trying to match the contents of HTML paragraph tags.  Consider:

```
input: '<p>paragraph one</p>'
regex: /<p>(.*)<\/p>/
```

This works as expected.  But if you have:

```
input: '<p>paragraph one</p><p>paragraph two</p>'
regex: /<p>(.*)<\/p>/
```

You will get the result:

```
'paragraph one</p></p>paragraph two'
```

Which is probably not what you wanted.  That's because `.*` is *greedy* by default: it matches all it can.  Making it lazy:

```
/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/
```

Will correctly match 'paragraph one' and 'paragraph two'.

Now, a note about your problem.  If you're trying to match something that you know is going to be at the end of your string, the "end of string" metacharacter (`$`) is your friend.  Also, as a general safety thing, it's not a bad idea to anticipate that there might be more than one whitespace character in your input.  So I would modify your code thusly:

```
preg_match('/PHPSESSID\s+(.*?)\s*$/',$getit,$session);
preg_match('/msid\s+(.*?)\s*$/',$getit,$msid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
preg_match('/PHPSESSID\s+(\S+)/', $getit, $session);
preg_match('/msid\s+(\S+)/', $getit, $msid);
```

Where `\S` stands for character that is not a space.